# Eigenvalues of matrix product $AB$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider two matrices $A$ and $B$ with eigenvalues lying strictly inside the unit circle. Moreover, $A$ is a positive definite matrix.

What can be said about the eigenvalues of $AB$? Are they also inside the unit circle?

Comment: @Sebastiano : this answer doesn't bring so much information for the case at hand (where $A$ is positive definite).

Comment: The eigenvalues of $AB$ may lie outside the open unit disc. Let $A=\pmatrix{1-\epsilon\\ &\epsilon}$ and $B=(1-\epsilon)\pmatrix{2&-1\\ 1&0}$. When $\epsilon=0$, one of the eigenvalues of $AB$ is equal to $2$. Therefore, when $\epsilon$ is positive and sufficiently small, one of the eigenvalues of $AB$ will be close to $2$.

Comment: @user1551 You are right. Sorry. I erase my comment.

Comment: @JeanMarie Ok, I retract the closure like as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are, *If both $A$ and $B$ are positive-definite*:

For any vector $v$ in your vector space, you have that $$\max_{|v|\leq1}|Av|$$ is equal to (in the finite-dimensional case) the (modulus of the) largest eigenvalue of $A$. Similarly, $\max_{|v|\leq1}|Bv|$ is (the modulus of) the largest eigenvalue of $B$, and thus we have $$\max_{|v|\leq1}|ABv|\leq\max_{|v|\leq1}|Av|\leq1.$$

In the next-to-last step, we used that $\{|v|\leq1\}$ is a superset of $\{Bv\colon |v|=1\}$.

EDIT: The intuition here is that *positive definite* matrices all move the unit ball to a subset of the unit ball; The statement "The unit ball is mapped to a subset of the unit ball" is equivalent to "the eigenvalues lie in the unit disk"

Comment: No. Your reasoning holds only if **both** $A$ and $B$ are  positive symmetric definite (psd) matrices. Indeed, it is for such matrices that you have property: $\max_{|v|\leq1}|Mv|=|\lambda_{max}|$(absolute value of the largest eigenvalue in absolute value). This property is false for general matrices. See counterexample by @user1551.

Comment: whoops forgot about that, thank you! I'll edit in why this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No. The largest-sized eigenvalue of $AB$ is unbounded.

In fact, given any nonzero real number $\gamma_1$, positive real numbers $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ and any $(\mu_1,\mu_2)$ that is either a pair of real numbers or a conjugate pair of complex numbers, there exist a positive definite matrix $A$ and a real matrix $B$ such that the spectra of $A,B$ and $AB$ are $\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2\},\{\mu_1,\mu_2\}$ and $\{\gamma_1,\gamma_2\}$ respectively, where $\gamma_2=\frac{1}{\gamma_1}\lambda_1\lambda_2\mu_1\mu_2$:

- if both $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are real, take
  $$
  A=\pmatrix{\dfrac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2}&\dfrac{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}{2}\\ \dfrac{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}{2}&\dfrac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2}}
  \quad\text{and}\quad
  B=\pmatrix{\mu_1&\dfrac{2(\gamma_1+\gamma_2)-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)(\mu_1+\mu_2)}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}\\ 0&\mu_2};
  $$
- if $(\mu_1,\mu_2)$ is a conjugate pair of complex numbers $x\pm iy$, take
  $$
  A=\pmatrix{\lambda_1\\ &\lambda_2}
  \quad\text{and}\quad
  B=\pmatrix{x+\delta&y^2+\delta^2\\ -1&x-\delta}
  $$
  where $\delta=\dfrac{(\gamma_1+\gamma_2)-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)x}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}$.

One may verify that in the constructions above, $\operatorname{tr}(A)=\lambda_1+\lambda_2$, $\det(A)=\lambda_1\lambda_2$, $\operatorname{tr}(B)=\mu_1+\mu_2$, $\det(B)=\mu_1\mu_2$ and $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\gamma_1+\gamma_2$. Therefore, by the definition of $\gamma_2$, we automatically obtain $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)=\lambda_1\lambda_2\mu_1\mu_2=\gamma_1\gamma_2$. Hence $\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2\},\{\mu_1,\mu_2\}$ and $\{\gamma_1,\gamma_2\}$ are indeed the spectra of $A,B$ and $AB$.

However, when $A$ is positive semidefinite and $B$ is Hermitian, the eigenvalues of $AB$ are bounded whenever the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are bounded, because
$$
\begin{aligned}
\rho(AB)&=\rho(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})\\
&=\|A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}\|_2\\
&\le\|A^{1/2}\|_2^2\|B\|_2\\
&=\rho(A^{1/2})^2\rho(B)\\
&=\rho(A)\rho(B).\\
\end{aligned}
$$
In particular, if the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ lies inside the open/closed unit disc, so do the eigenvalues of $AB$.